# Restore from a Fusion Drive to a standard hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, ssd, fusion-drive

I have an iMac with a built in Fusion Drive. I have switched to using an external Thunderbolt SSD as my boot disk, and I would now like to back up and wipe the internal Fusion Drive so that it can be a Time Machine volume for my new SSD - I'm just backing it up to  make sure I won't miss any files that are accidentally left on there.

I've read about using the 'Restore...' functionality in Disk Utility to image one disk onto another, so that you basically have an exact clone of it. However, when I go to "Restore" *from* my Fusion Drive *to a regular disk* (separate to the ones I've mentioned so far), the Fusion Drive shows as two devices in the Source list (the SSD & the HDD part).

Can you image the entire contents of a Fusion Drive onto a single HDD?

Comment: 1. I would just use Finder to drag and drop important files off the Fusion drive.
2. Using internal drive as a backup disk is not ideal as it fails to mitigate the risk of hardware failure of other components inside the Mac.  Perhaps better to use your internal disk as additional data space and backup both that and your external boot SSD to an external backup disk.